# Interacting with webpage through script?

Tags: scripting, web

I have an email-account where I've ended-up with *a lot* (200 000) of messages in the Spam-folder.  Unfortunately, it's not all spam - partly due to badly trained filter and partly due to mail-list digests containing one or two messages of many that triggers the filter.

I'd like to download these messages, but POP can't access any folder but INBOX and IMAP chockes (crash on the server) because of the large number of messages.

I'm left with having to use the web-mail to move mail from Spam to INBOX - by doing "wait until page is loaded", "mark all messages", "Select INBOX", "Move marked messages to chosen folder"...  ...and repeat!  But with only 500 or 1000 messages per page, moving 100 000 messages will require a lot of work.

Is there a good way of doing this automatically?

I thought about using `expect` with `lynx` or `links`, but the web-mail interface uses some JavaScript so I doubt it would work...  `wget` is (AFAIK) not suited for something like this...  Is there perhaps a way to "remote control" `chrome`, `firefox` or `opera` (or `X` itself) through scripting?

What I'm really looking for (I guess), is some sort of "virtual web-browser" that works like a normal web-browser, but which is controlled by scripts...

Comment: There are none that I know of.  Taking a guess, I would say that the webmail system running on the server is some version of [Horde](http://www.horde.org/apps/webmail).  All plugins for it are server side only.

Comment: Selenium is one of the options.

Comment: I should have worded myself more carefully...  I'm really looking for a *general* way to automate this kind of interaction on a web-browser.  Although I'll be using it first to move my mail; I'm after a general way to automate similar repetitive actions.  Eg. hit a check-box, hit a radio-button, hit a push-button, wait, repeat -- not just for this particular web-mail system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the web interface uses javascript and cannot function without it, then you should use [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) directly in your programming language of choice, (or if you are using Python you can also use an abstraction layer like [splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/).

It is becoming less common for sites that require javascript to function without javascript at all. You can however easily check that by switching javascript off in your browser temporarily. If javascript is not required, but cookies are, then a less heavy mechanism as selenium can be used (e.g. python + [mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/). Apart from URLs you most often have to deal with cookies from login to request and from request to request, trivial in selenium (and mechanize) not so easy when using `wget` etc.

An alternative could be that, if you can download your INBOX without problems, you move the messages from your INBOX to some temporary storage, move all of the SPAM folder contents to your INBOX and then download the INBOX, clean it out and restore INBOX from the temporary storage.